# How to create parallel offsets for edges

Tags: edges

When I create offsets, this is the situation I am faced with:

[image]

However the orange lines are not parallel to the black line in the middle (or parallel to each other for that matter).

This is the situation I would like to have:

[image]

What can I do to make my offsets parallel? Is there a specific setting I need to adjust?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prefer using Bevel instead of offset edge slide.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>E</kbd> to make them parallel to the adjacent edge, then <kbd>F</kbd> if you need to make them parallel to the opposite adjacent edge